# How to include libraries in NDK AndroidStudio Experimental Gradle

Tags: android, android-ndk

I made the android studio working with NDK. but im using android experimental and so there is no Android.mk or Application.mk file. can anyone help me how can i include libraries (C or C++ libraries) into my code?

Comment: Please avoid open-ended questions like _"can someone help me with X?"_, as we don't know exactly what part of X you're having trouble with, and therefore have no way of knowing what would qualify as an answer to the question. Have you read the section of [NDK dependencies](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental#TOC-NDK-Dependencies) on the experimental gradle plugin page?

Comment: @Michael Noted and thankyou.